# Вывод в трее

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите кто что знает...обратились сделать сайт на wordpress и пишут типа "помимо сайта нужны скрипты, которые будут выводить зарегистрированным пользователям сайта виджеты и информеры на рабочем столе" где можно про такое вычитать???

Answer (score 1):

На рабочем столе?

Издеваемся?

Виджеты – это простые мини-программы, которые украшают рабочий стол и облегчают доступ к разнообразной информации.

Написаны они обычно под ОС на С/С++/Delphi и прочих языках.

На рабочем столе компьютера или на рабочем столе WP? описать подробнее нужно!

если про WP то можно [тут](http://i-novice.net/kak-napisat-wordpress-vidzhet/) глянуть

И название вопроса изменить нужно, какой к черту трей?!